# Are there any W3C recomendations to add a local shared object (Flash) type system to javascript

Tags: javascript, w3c

Currently local storage for javascript is limited to cookies, which makes robust client side programs fairly limited as as soon as you start getting into many kilobytes of cookie data most servers start to throw 400 errors. Besides when it comes to saving client state in some cases you don't need the server to know whats going on.

So what I'm asking is does anyone know if a local shared object type thing is on the books for the future of javascript?

Comment: Hmmn I guess I should have phrased my question are cookies the only way to store data on a client connection for javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's HTML5 localStorage and sessionStorage.
See: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Comment: fantastic boy theres some great stuff on the editors desk for html 5